# Update a range of rows in a table where the condition is in another table

Tags: sql

example:

table 1

```
invoice line article price
1       1    pen       10
1       2    mouse     11
1       3    paper     15
2       1    ...       25
2       2    ...       80
2       3    ...     
2       4    ....
```

table 2

```
invoice    date
1          2014-01-03 00:00:00.0000
2          2014-05-12 00:00:00.0000
3          2014-06-17 00:00:00.0000
```

how can I update the price only on the rows where the invoice date is for example the month of november

I know that i must use a join but i'm already joining this table for doing other stuff in the same query:

```
UPDATE invoicelines
SET invoicelines.netprice = ART.price
FROM invoicelines IL INNER JOIN items ITM
ON IL.item = ITM.item
```

i want to update the invoicelines with a specified date, but this date is in another table, and the situation is similar to the first example

Comment: just use update statement based on your filter

Comment: This i a basic JOIN problem http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
set    price = price + 10
from   table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.invoice = t2.invoice
where  month(t2.date) = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

As to "I know that i must use a join": No, you don't have to join. When a condition is in another table you would usually use EXISTS or IN.

```
update table1
set price = ...
where invoice in 
(
  select invoice 
  from table2
  where month(`date`) = 11
);
```

Or:

```
update table1
set price = ...
where exists 
(
  select * 
  from table2 
  where month(table2.`date`) = 11 
  and table2.invoice = table1.invoice
);
```

You forgot to name your dbms. Date functions are mostly dbms specific, so a MONTH function may be available or not.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved With This

```
UPDATE Invoicelines
SET Invoicelines.NetPrice = ART.Price
FROM Invoicelines BR INNER JOIN Items ART join InvoiceHead bt on month(bt.docdate)=11 
ON BR.Item = ART.Item
where BR.sheetNumber=bt.sheetNumber
```